# Тандем как группа из более 2-х человек

Tags: лексика

"Тандем" в значении "союз" может обозначать более двух человек? Союз из трех, четырех и т. д. Если ответ положительный, то всякий союз при таком случае может называться тандемом?

Comment: Писать "двух", как у Вас (2-x), грубая ошибка. Наращиваются только порядковые числительные. А вообще, в данном случае лучше писать словом, а не цифрой.

Answer (score 2):

Как технический термин слово употребимо по отношению к механизмам из *двух и более* соосно расположенных частей. Однако в переносном смысле, при употреблении по отношению к людям, оно прочно ассоциируется (по аналогии с *простейшим* техническим тандемом - двухместным велосипедом) с совместной деятельностью только *двух* человек, которые дополняют друг друга. Из "Современной энциклопедии", 2000:

> В переносном смысле - о *двух* спортсменах, следующих на дистанции или
>   по результатам друг за другом, а также о *двух* лицах, объединенных
>   общим делом, действующих сообща (например, творческий тандем).

Если таких людей больше двух, говорят о *группе*, *творческом союзе* или *команде*.

Answer (score -1):

Tandem — последовательно соединённый, поэтому ответы: 1) да. 2) нет.

Не используйте такие слова и не будет вопросов, у читателей в том числе.

Comment: В числе кого находятся читатели?

Comment: @Alex_ander уточните вопрос.

Comment: Это _проверочный вопрос к предложению_: если в нём самом ответа не находится, то выражение "в том числе" употреблено некорректно. Если "читатели" принадлежат какой-то группе людей, у которых "не будет вопросов", эта группа (общее понятие, на которое затем ссылаются как на "то число") должна быть названа в первой части предложения, иначе "в том числе" повисает в воздухе. Да, такое часто слышится из телевизора, тем не менее, это ненормативное употребление выражения.

Comment: @Alex_ander, а, понял, подразумевал спрашивающего и читателей в том числе. Спасибо за уточнение.